# Como restringir o acesso a página de registo de usuários?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.2

Pessoal seguinte estou criando um projeto em laravel 5.2 usei as classes de auth do próprio laravel.

E gostaria de saber como posso estar configurando o mesmo para que a pagina `/register` seja acessada somente depois que o usuário realizar o login. Pois como padrão a mesma vem sem validação e qualquer pessoa pode acessar.

Minha route.php esta da seguinte maneira:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
//
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
});


Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  Route::auth();
  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
  //Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta alterar os middlewares do controller de autenticação para:

```
/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'register', 'showRegistrationForm']]);
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['register', 'showRegistrationForm']]);
}
```

Adicionei os métodos `register` e `showRegistrationForm` no middleware `auth` e retirei do `guest`, caso contrário o usuário seria redirecionado para a home caso ele estivesse logado.

Comment: Ficou legal porém me surgiu mais uma duvida, quando eu realizar o login ele sempre direciona para o register como faço para ele redirecionar para /dashboard por exemplo e só acessar register se eu chamar.

Comment: @DouglasSalomão isso já é uma pergunta diferente. Dúvidas diferentes precisam ser tratadas em tópicos diferentes. Faça um [tour] para compreender melhor como funciona o SO-PT.

Comment: Ok obrigado irei dar uma pesquisada.